# Flutter: How to dry-render a widget and get its size?

Tags: flutter, widget

I'm trying to get the size of a widget. A common approach is to give a `GlobalKey()` to a widget, and retrieve its size **after it has been laid out and shown to the user**. Given the constraint (`MediaQuery.of(context).size.width`), is there a way to pre-render a widget and get its size (specifically height) before building the real one?

Edit: I want the height so badly because I need to pass the height to `SliverAppBar`. I can build the content first, and use `setState` to resize it after it get laid out. But this also mean that screen will flicker for once.

Comment: Isn't that what IntrinsicHeight/Width do?

Comment: Nope, I need a number.

Comment: Take a look at Boxy in the pub, then.

Comment: maybe `Custom[Single|Multi]ChildLayout` is what you need?

Comment: Can you kindly show me how?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz, I thought of using `boxy` too, but I couldn't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Offstage`. The trick is to use `Offstage` to render, then rebuild the moment you get the size using the `postframecallback`.

```
class _wrapperState extends State<wrapper> with WidgetsBindingObserver
{
    Size? widgetSize;
    GlobalKey widgetKey = GlobalKey();
    late Widget sourceWidget;

    @override
    void initState()
    {
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);

        // widget.child is your main widget you're trying to get the size.
        sourceWidget = widget.child;

        super.initState();
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context)
    {
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_)
        {
            if (widgetSize == null)
            {
                setState(()
                {
                    widgetSize = widgetKey.currentContext!.size;
                });
            }
        });

        // Assign a key to your widget so that we can get its size later.
        // Also this key will prevent the widget to get built twice.
        Widget finalWidget = KeyedSubtree(
            key: widgetKey,
            child: sourceWidget
        );

        // If we don't have the size, then do the offstage.
        // Postframe will kick off right after this.
        if (widgetSize == null)
        {
            return Offstage(
                child: Material(
                    body: Stack(
                        children: [
                            Positioned(
                                top: 0,
                                left: 0,
                                child: finalWidget,
                            )
                        ],
                    ),
                ),
            );
        }

        // Now we do have our size.
        // Do your main build now.
        return MyComplexWidget();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try offstage widget. So the layout will look like

```dart
Offstage(
 offstage: true,
 child: Container (
   key: widgetKey
 )
)
```

Comment: Still, I can't get the height in `initState`, I need to get the height before I render the real one. Using offstage means that the real one and the offstage one will get built at the same time.

Comment: You cannot get it in init state

Comment: `Offset` may work, but I have to do it in an extremely hacky way.

Comment: Yeah absolutely